# awk/sed broken line how to fix and move some lines

Tags: sed, awk

I have a few lines that are broken and I want those lines to be moved up to the prior line

I need help to fix this file text 
Source:

```
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\Ser
             vice_Legal 
    Access : BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
             MLIDDOMAIN1\Domain Admins Allow  FullControl
             MLIDDOMAIN1\acl_corp_gs_legal Allow  Modify, Synchronize
    -----------------------
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\balco 
    Access : Everyone Allow  FullControl
             Everyone Allow  268435456
    -----------------------
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\BCDRP
             lanning 
    Access : Everyone Allow  FullControl
             Everyone Allow  268435456
    -----------------------
```

Expected result:

```
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\Service_Legal 
    Access : BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
    -----------------------
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\balco 
    Access : Everyone Allow  FullControl
             Everyone Allow  268435456
    -----------------------
    Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\eiesc1\BCDRPlanning 
    Access : Everyone Allow  FullControl
             Everyone Allow  268435456
    -----------------------
```

I only was able to run `awk "/Path/{a=1;next}/Access/{a=0}a"` to find which are the lines that are broken, but I do not know how to move those lines up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/^Path/{N;s/\n         //;}'
```

Comment: Oddly enough, when I tried this I found two problems. First, `Path` does not appear to be right at the start of the string (in the example file there was white space before); and this leaves some space in between the lines. Both may be caused by unwanted spaces introduced in the copy/paste operation. How would you modify this to work with leading spaces on each line?

Comment: I was going to leave the answer as "variable". Can that be done? A simple thing like `[ ]+` instead of the fixed string of spaces didn't seem to work...

Comment: @Floris: `sed '/^ *Path/{N;/^ *Access/!s/\n *//;}'`

Comment: I get `s: event not found`... which I fix with `\!s`; but now the "unbroken" Path line is joined with the Access line that follows it. It is my copy of `sed`? (Mac OS 10.7.5)

Comment: @Floris: I'm not sure. All I can suggest is that you study the command, understand why it ought to work, then experiment with simpler commands until you isolate the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You want to hold off on printing your `Path` lines until you've seen the next line and if the next line isn't an `Access` line then you want to print the two lines together.

Something like:

```
/Path/ {
    a=$0
    next
}

a && !/Access/ {
    gsub(/^ */, "")
    printf "%s",a
    print
    a=""
    next
}

1
```

Comment: Would this work if the path was broken across more than one line? It was not explicit from the question but it looks like it would be possible...

Comment: Not as written. You could make it do that by continuing to accumulate into a though and only printing when you saw Access.